# zipline RLock issue

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, zipline

I have successfully downloaded `zipline` using `conda` but I keep getting this error when I try to import it into a program in jupyter notebook. I am relatively new to `zipline` so pardon me if the the solution is obvious. Please advise as I cannot find a solution anywhere and quantopian said this is an anaconda, not `zipline` issue.

Error:

```
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\logbook\concurrency.py in <module>()
     29 
     30 if has_gevent:
---> 31     from gevent._threading import (Lock as ThreadLock,
     32                                    RLock as ThreadRLock,
     33                                    get_ident as 

thread_get_ident,

ImportError: cannot import name 'RLock

Successful install ==>
Solving environment: |
Warning: 4 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda::ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0, anaconda::openssl-1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0
  - anaconda::ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0, defaults::openssl-1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0
  - anaconda::openssl-1.0.2o-h8ea7d77_0, defaults::ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0
  - defaults::ca-certificates-2018.03.07-0, defaults::openssl-1.0.2o-h8ea7d77done
```

**Note:** All requested packages are already installed.

Answer (score 0):

This solution didn't work for me but it did work for others. tl;dr update `logbook` and uninstall `gevent`:
https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/2208

```
=== My solution ===
```

Turns out my issue was basic environment handling. I had installed a conda env with python version 3.5, but ipython that was installed by default used python version 2.7. Solution:

```
conda install ipython
```

then running an example will not throw an error:

```
cd zipline/examples
ipython
%run buyapple.py
```